# Elasticsearch: What would be the lowest-cost, highest-impact change I can make to decrease response times?

Tags: elasticsearch, scalability

Unguided beginners in any field often find themselves barking up the wrong tree in trying to solve a problem — this question is asked in hoping that it'll vector my approach in a more direct path towards solving the problem.

---

On to the question:

I'm about a month into working with ES and so far it's been awesome. I've been incrementally indexing to ES from a set of data I've got in CSV, and I'm beginning to encounter slow response times. I want to bring the response time down, but don't know what's a good way / the best way to approach it.

My research thus far tells me that it really depends on a number of variables. So, listed below are details on the ES variables which might help you with writing an answer:

- **Shards & Stuff**

  - I say "& Stuff" because I don't know enough to know what's significant here.
  - Running the default ES settings, 5 shards, 1 node.
  - Running index-time-search-as-you-type, exactly as-is from the [ES guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html). There's a bit in there which `PUT`s settings for the indices: `"number_of_shards": 1`. I'm not sure how that affects things.
- **Index**

  - 2 indices with similar mappings (mirror a DB, so don't want to combine them)
  - Multi-language, but at the moment I only care about English.
  - As mentioned above, configured for index-time-search-as-you-type (min: 3, max: 20).
- **Documents**

  - Have currently indexed ~1mil documents.
  - Have total of ~4mil documents to index.
  - Very short documents, like 5 fields of 10 english words per doc.
  - Total CSV filesize of all ~4mil rows is only ~400MB.
- **Queries**

  - Main query is run as a bool (should) query.
  - Heavy on score scripting.
  - Heavy on script-sorted aggregations.
  - Fuzzy search (fuzziness: 1).
- **Hardware**

  - Running [Linode's $20/mo VPS](https://www.linode.com/pricing).
- **Response Time**

  - Queries with very high frequencies (typically a single English word) in the index are taking forever (~7-9000ms) to return results.
  - More specific queries (>=2 eng words) return more acceptable response times (~2-3000ms).
  - Ideally, all response times should be <2s.

If there are other variables which are important, and I've missed out, let me know and I'll edit them in.

Thank you!

Comment: here are some articles that i'll think can help you https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html

Comment: Can you post the query which is taking 7-9s?  Also, is your index data stored locally, or over a network mount?

Answer (score 0):

I turned [caching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-shard-query-cache.html) on (kinda a stop-gap measure) and it has helped a bunch. Meets my needs for now.